# How do I leave people's home streets?

Tags: glitch-2011

I entered someone's home street through a visiting stone, but now I can't figure out how to leave. I walked to both ends, but there's no sign to go anywhere. How do I get out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To leave houses, click the imagination bubble in the top-left corner, then click "Return to World", the right-most option.

[image]